# Facebook commerce API calling error commerce_account_read_settings, commerce_manage_accounts

Tags: facebook, orders, commerce

We want to FB commerce API and download orders. But nothing is working as FB documentation suggested. We tried to connect with FB support but they have all untrained team members who dont know anything about it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/order-management/order-api/

https://graph.facebook.com/1145228135858524/commerce_orders

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#200) Application does not have required permission commerce_account_read_settings, commerce_manage_accounts or the capability to make this API call. In case of permissions, your app must be live and have approved permissions for accessing regular shop.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "AoyypaWYG7FI2QhFB2SuBHA"
}
```

}

We have completed all steps like Business approval, APP approval etc and live mode.

I also tried FB graph API tool to check orders but getting same error their too.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%7Bcms-id%7D%2Fcommerce_orders%3Ffields%3Did%252Cbuyer_details%252Cchannel%252Cmerchant_order_id%252Corder_status

See below some other FB using same errors.

https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/425867408826859/

Can anyone just answers if you ever tried to call FB commerce API to get Orders ?

Comment: We can't possible answer this. You've posted no code, so we can't diagnose that, and we're not FaceBook, so we can't address any permissions problems. See [ask]

Comment: Can you just answers if you ever tried to call FB commerce API to get Orders ?